# Android TextInputLayout remove extra space below edittext

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext, material-design, android-textinputlayout

I'm using `TextInputLayout.FilledBox.Dense` as style for my `TextInputLayout` and then I disable the hint by adding `hintEnabled=false` but then It adds extra line at the bottom of `EditText`

Code snippet

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/name_text_input"
          style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.Dense"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:hintAnimationEnabled="false"
            app:hintEnabled="false">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/login_tab_userid3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: @renzadar , please have a look in the below solution and let me know in case of concern

Comment: What does it mean "extra line" ?

Comment: there is an extra space below the edittext line

Comment: Check if it happens also with com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the line below the your `EditText` from this **`android:background="@null"`**   and then creating the `View` below your `EditText` for creating the line below the `EditText`

```
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@null"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_height="0.5dp"/>
```

Comment: Check the [doc](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/TextInputLayout.md#filled-box-default): Note: When using a filled text field with an `EditText` child that is not a `TextInputEditText`, make sure to set the EditText's `android:background` to `@null`. This allows `TextInputLayout` to set a filled background on the `EditText`.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti ok i am editing the answer, thanks for a input

Answer (score 0):

In your editText

Put this line : **`android:background="@null"`**